# Help with a curl command and reading from a file

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, curl, github

I have a curl command that needs to make a post and send my ssh key as one of the params, the command I am using looks like this:

```
SSH_KEY=`cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`;
curl -d "login=username&token=apikey&title=test&key=$SSH_KEY" http://github.com/api/v2/yaml/repos/key/username/somerepo/add
```

The problem is that there is a `+` in the ssh key and the string is terminating at that point, how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently in version 7.18.0 curl added the --data-urlencode option:

```
curl --data-urlencode "login=username&token=apikey&title=test&key=$SSH_KEY" http://github.com/api/v2/yaml/repos/key/username/somerepo/add
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `--data-urlencode` instead of `-d`.

Answer (score 0):

```
urlencode()
```

Is what I think your looking for? You can have special characters automatically replaced by using urlencode() on the string.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php for more information on it.

Also more information on: curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html do a page search for: **urlencode**

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

To send a file add '@' in front of the filename

```
curl -d "login=username&token=apikey&title=test&key=@~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub" \
http://github.com/api/v2/yaml/repos/key/username/somerepo/add
```

Hope this helps.